# Hive : Load data from Multi-level directory

Tags: hive

I want to Load data from Multi-level directory to my hive table.but the error is:

```
hive> LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://hadoop1:9000/logClassify/unLock' INTO
 TABLE unLock;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path 
>   ''hdfs://hadoop1:9000/logClassify/unLock'': source contains directory:
>   hdfs://hadoop1:9000/logClassify/unLock/2016

I  have sett the params  in the hive-site.xml file:

```
<property>
     <name>mapred.input.dir.recursive</name>
     <value>true</value> 
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories</name>
    <value>true</value>   
</property>
```

I don't know why?

Comment: it seems that you have year wise data in your hdfs://hadoop1:9000/logClassify/unLock directory. Better use hive partitioning and create a partition column year.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to loda data from local storage

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/data' INTO TABLE table_name;
```

and if you want to data from hdfs just remove LOCAL

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/user/data' INTO TABLE table_name;
```

Comment: there is no need to add host name ( hdfs://hadoop1:9000) into your path

Comment: and your above error 'source contains directory: hdfs://hadoop1:9000/logClassify/unLock/2016' said this location contain the directory so give it the proper destination path of your file.

Comment: I would like recursive subdirectory，Because there are many files in different subdirectories.

Comment: so you have to give that subdirectories path because here hive cant find the proper file which you want to load.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in Hive command line interface enter:

```
set hive.input.dir.recursive=true;
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
set hive.supports.subdirectories=true;
```

After that, load the data. For example if you have one level directories:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH "/data/testdata/*" INTO TABLE testtable;
```

For two-level directories:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/data/testdata/* /*' INTO TABLE testtable;
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in Hive command line interface enter:

**set hive.input.dir.recursive=true;**

set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;

set hive.supports.subdirectories=true;

After that, load the data. For example if you have one level directories:

***LOAD DATA INPATH "/data/testdata/*" INTO TABLE testtable;***

For two-level directories:

***LOAD DATA INPATH '/data/testdata/* /*' INTO TABLE testtable;***

Hope this will help.